# mysql trigger or php code

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySQL database that has 21 tables, in each table I have 'created' column(timestamp).
this field holds insert time of row.

However:

1- I can write a trigger for fill the column for each table like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `created` BEFORE INSERT ON `some_table`
 FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.`created`=NOW()
```

2- I can handle it by PHP:

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,created)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,now()) ");
```

I concerned about writing trigger for each table has overhead. Is it right?
which one is better specific on performance?
which one is better at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not need to fill this column yourself if you configure the TIMESTAMP properties for it...
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html

To clarify from the documentation here is a working example of how subsequent updates do not change a timestamp field when correctly configured for the desired behaviour

```
create temporary table example (apID int auto_increment, 
                      audit timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
                      name varchar(50),
                      primary key(apID));
insert into example(name) values('test');
select * from example;
update example set name='tes' where apID=1;
select * from example;
```

Comment: I know that! but it update the field for each UPDATE query, not just for INSERT. If you read my question carefully I said the 'created' field holds insert time, not every update time!

Comment: And in the documentation it says that the UPDATE only happens when it is configured to do so - therefore if it is currently changing on UPDATE, change your DDL.  Apologies but I don't see how I misread it - you're asking after how you can populate this field as far as I can tell as you only mention INSERTs with no DUPLCIATE KEY mentions.  If however this is not case, please update your question to more clearly indicate what you're after.

Comment: If you read the documentation carefully,by "configuring the TIMESTAMP properties"(as you said) you can't prevent mysql to update this column in UPDATE queries that changes other columns.
it is simple question: I want to hold only insert time in 'created' column...

Comment: @ArashMousavi -I have updated my answer to show the behaviour that the doc states: •With a DEFAULT clause but no ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clause, the column has the given default value and is not automatically updated to the current timestamp.